# Is there a way to set up a python socket so that the server only sends when the client asks for an updated value?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I am trying to get a value from one python script into another.
the first script must stay running constantly, and the receiving script can't run constantly and needs to get the latest value from the first.

Right now the script does function barely. but since the receiver is running slower than the sender, a backlog forms. I also need a way to continue the second script with the previous value if there is no new data from the sender. Otherwise, the program hangs when the sender stops.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
tabletPressure = "Value constantly updates while pen is pressed, value is between 0,4096"

while True:
    if pen_pressed:
        intValue = int(tabletPressure)
        bytesValue = (intValue).to_bytes(4, byteorder="little")
        sock.sendto(bytesValue,("0.0.0.0", 33335))
```

The receiving script looks like this

```
import socket
import time

dataBus = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dataBus.bind(('0.0.0.0', 33335))


def modal(self, context, event):

    if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
        self.cancel(context)
        self.dataBus.close()
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    if event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
        data, addr = dataBus.recvfrom(4)
        print(int.from_bytes(data, byteorder="little"))
```

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the use of redis for this purpose?  It can be easily spun up in a docker container and is often utilized as a message broker between client / server tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the server to only send its message when it receives one.  Example:

server.py

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('',5000))

counter = 0

def datagram_server():
    while True:
        data,addr = s.recvfrom(4096)                # receive any message
        s.sendto(counter.to_bytes(4,'little'),addr) # respond to client address

Thread(target=datagram_server,daemon=True).start()

while True:
    sleep(.5)
    counter += 1 # constantly updating value
```

client.py

```
from socket import *
from time import sleep

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
server = 'localhost',5000
ping = b'' # message content doesn't matter

def get_latest_counter():
    s.sendto(ping,server)      # ping server to get a response
    data,addr = s.recvfrom(4)  # get the response
    return int.from_bytes(data,'little')

while True:
    print(get_latest_counter())
    sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
5
7
9
11
```